# Bad state: Stream has already been listened to socket_io_client

Tags: flutter, dart, socket.io, stream

I'm encountering an issue in my Flutter application where I'm getting the error message "Bad state: Stream has already been listened to." The error is being triggered in a specific widget that uses a stream from another class. Here's a simplified version of the code:

I have a class StreamSocket that handles a stream of responses:

[Docs](https://pub.dev/packages/socket_io_client/versions/1.0.2)

Stream Socket get:

```
my_order_ongoing_page.dart:


class MyOrderOngoing extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyOrderOngoing({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyOrderOngoing> createState() => _MyOrderOngoingState();
}

class _MyOrderOngoingState extends State<MyOrderOngoing>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController tabController;
  final Stream<String> _responseData = streamSocket.getResponse;

  @override
  void initState() {
    tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    tabController.dispose();
    streamSocket.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextTheme textTheme = Theme.of(context).textTheme;

    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: whitebgColor,
        appBar: AppBar(
          toolbarHeight: 80,
          elevation: 0.7,
          backgroundColor: whitebgColor,
          title: AppbarFoodBourge(textTheme: textTheme),
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
            child: SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          child: StreamBuilder(
            stream: streamSocket.getResponse,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                // Check if there's data in the snapshot
                return Container(
                  child: Text(snapshot.data ??
                      "Null"), // Display the data using Text widget for example
                );
              } else {
                return Container(); // Return an empty container if there's no data yet
              }
            },
          ),
        )));
  }
}
```

I have tried many solution but neither of worked.